# Generate dates 21 days before and after index date in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data frame with 10,000+ dates. for example,

```
indexdt
01-02-2019
08-15-2019
```

I need to create a data frames such that I get same day of week, upto 3 weeks before and after the index date. The generated dates should not include the index date.
Final table

```
indexdt       dates
01-02-2019  12-26-2018
01-02-2019  12-19-2018
01-02-2019  12-12-2018
01-02-2019  01-09-2019
01-02-2019  01-16-2019
01-02-2019  01-23-2019
08-15-2019  07-25-2019
08-15-2019  08-01-2019
08-15-2019  08-08-2019
08-15-2019  08-22-2019
08-15-2019  08-29-2019
08-15-2019  08-05-2019
```

I am looking for a data.table solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DT[, indexdt := as.Date(indexdt, "%m-%d-%Y")]
DT[, .(dates = indexdt + 7 * c(-3:-1, 1:3)), by = indexdt]

#        indexdt      dates
#  1: 2019-01-02 2018-12-12
#  2: 2019-01-02 2018-12-19
#  3: 2019-01-02 2018-12-26
#  4: 2019-01-02 2019-01-09
#  5: 2019-01-02 2019-01-16
#  6: 2019-01-02 2019-01-23
#  7: 2019-08-15 2019-07-25
#  8: 2019-08-15 2019-08-01
#  9: 2019-08-15 2019-08-08
# 10: 2019-08-15 2019-08-22
# 11: 2019-08-15 2019-08-29
# 12: 2019-08-15 2019-09-05
```

If you rather keep the original date formatting (as strings)

```
DT[, .(dates = indexdt + 7 * c(-3:-1, 1:3)), by = indexdt
   ][, lapply(.SD, format, "%m-%d-%Y")]

#        indexdt      dates
#  1: 01-02-2019 12-12-2018
#  2: 01-02-2019 12-19-2018
#  3: 01-02-2019 12-26-2018
#  ...
```

Data

```
DT <- data.table(
  indexdt = c("01-02-2019", "08-15-2019")
)
```

Comment: Awesome!  Thank you very much Sindri_baldur!